# GCP BigQuery throwing Invalid URL while trying get_status of the schema even though the schema exists

Tags: google-bigquery

The schema very well exists and I can copy and run on the BigQuery. 
In the requirements.txt we are using the latest package (google-cloud-bigquery)

> exception Invalid URL 'None/bigquery/v2/projects/XXXXXX/XXXXX
>   No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://None/bigquery/v2/projects/XXXX/XXX

Code snippet:

```
client = bigquery.Client(project="XXXXXXXX")
client_bq.get_table(table_ref)
```

Comment: can you detail the code that builds that table_ref?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what exactly you are passing with that variable `table_ref`, so I'm going to explain what that method is expecting, hope that helps you to get it right.

> **Note**: be careful your `client` object is used as `client_bq`, that won't
>   run.

The method `client.get_table(table_ref)` ([docs](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.get_table)) is expecting a `table_ref` that according to the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.table.Table.html#google.cloud.bigquery.table.Table) is a pointer to a table, and if `table_ref` is a `string`, it must include a `project ID`, `dataset ID`, and `table ID`, each separated by a `.` (dot), for example, from a public dataset of BigQuery:

```
table_ref = "bigquery-public-data.noaa_historic_severe_storms.storms_2019"
```

Given this `table_ref` the following code should work:

```
client = bigquery.Client(project="my_project_id")
client.get_table(table_ref)
```

On the other hand, if you want to create `table_ref` as a `Table` object, notice that you don't need to provide an `schema`, this parameter is optional ([docs](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.table.Table.html#google.cloud.bigquery.table.Table)).

```
table_ref = bigquery.table.Table("bigquery-public-data.noaa_historic_severe_storms.storms_2019")
```

If your goal is create a valid `schema`, in the [docs](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/reference.html#schema) states that this is build with `SchemaField` objects, the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.schema.SchemaField.html#google.cloud.bigquery.schema.SchemaField) is the best reference at this point, if you want a sample you can get it by saving the `Table` object and getting the `schema` attribute as follows:

```
>>> table = client.get_table(table_ref)
>>> table.schema
```

*(running the code in a Python console)*

**Sample Output:**

```
[SchemaField('magnitude', 'FLOAT', 'NULLABLE', 'Description', ()),
SchemaField('magnitude_type', 'STRING', 'NULLABLE', 'Description', ()),
SchemaField('flood_cause', 'STRING', 'NULLABLE', 'Description', ())]
```